# Border left top cut

Tags: html, css

I need help to know how to cut the top of the border on the left like in the link below. Do I have to make a list or can I have divs to do so?

http://codepen.io/FilipDanic/pen/dPNRQm

```
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i> Home</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i> Inbox <span class="unread">2</span></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg"></i> Settings</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"></i> Log-out</li>
    </ul>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body{
  background: url('https://unsplash.imgix.net/44/9s1lvXLlSbCX5l3ZaYWP_hdr-1.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&s=fd39ab9358b1aec7746ee67168ccf268') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

ul{
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 400px;
  background: #34495e;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul>li{
  color: #fff;
  background: #34495e;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  border-left: 0.5em groove #e74c3c;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s all;
}

i{
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.active{
  border-left: 0.5em groove #1abc9c;
}
```

...

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you want. Right now I don't understand the "cut border" part.

Comment: Means ??? I really dont understand your problem?

Comment: The border on the left (groove) is cut in a vertical manner on top. When i would put a groove border on the left of a div for example i would get the top and bottom of that border to be diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `border-top: 0.5em groove #2c3e50;` to your `ul > li` style definitions.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPpVpd

[image: Screenshot of codepen output]

Answer (score 0):

This is simply adding `border-left` and `border-bottom` with different colors. This could be done to any element like a `div`:

```
div{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    border-left: 10px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 10px solid purple;    
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5st50no/)

The trick is stacking them while the `border-bottom` color is a shade of the `background-color`, and the `border-left` being some other color:

```
div{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    border-left: 10px solid purple;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #c20c08;    
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5st50no/2/)